# Slave server option not visible in Spoon

Tags: hadoop, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

In my company we have an Hadoop based ETL solution. These are some of the steps being invoked in our data-flow:

1. Exporting data from SQL Server
2. Importing into Hive
3. Applying transformations etc
4. Storing processed data into Solr

Our goal is to be able to manage the entire ETL process from Spoon. To achieve that I have been trying to use carte server in order to execute spoon jobs remotely. The problem is that currently I dont see any "Slave server" option under the View panel of Spoon. I am using Community Edition and version 7.1. Is that a feature of EE or am I missing some configuration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to see a "slave server" option? By "slave servers" do you mean the data nodes in the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we couldn't find a way to execute jobs through carte (with v7.1) we decided to follow the simplest approach of SSH commands which works fine